# Module `EmployeeFormReducer` does not exist in the Haste module map

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I was working on my React Native application and reloaded the Simulator when I got this error:

> Module `EmployeeFormReducer` does not exist in the Haste module map

`EmployeeFormReducer` is a reducer that I already had, I added the `EMPLOYEE_UPDATE` case right before I tested it in the Simulator:

```
import { EMPLOYEE_UPDATE } from '../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  name: '',
  phone: '',
  shift: ''
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case EMPLOYEE_UPDATE:
      return { ...state, [action.payload.prop]: action.payload.value };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

I did not forget to add it to my combineReducers:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import AuthReducer from './AuthReducer';
import EmployeeFormReducer from 'EmployeeFormReducer';

export default combineReducers({
  auth: AuthReducer,
  employeeForm: EmployeeFormReducer
});
```

I figured it was based on the documented React Native issue on facebooks github:

> This might be related to
>   https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4968 To resolve try
>   the following:
>     1. Clear watchman watches: `watchman watch-del-all`.
>     2. Delete the `node_modules` folder: `rm -rf node_modules && npm install`.
>     3. Reset Metro Bundler cache: `rm -rf /tmp/metro-bundler-cache-*` or `npm start -- --reset-cache`.  4. Remove haste cache: `rm -rf
>   /tmp/haste-map-react-native-packager-*

but I ran all those commands and I am still getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your import you should specify a path to the file you want to import, look at how you import 'AuthReducer', so your import for 'EmployeeFormReducer' should be:

```
 import EmployeeFormReducer from './EmployeeFormReducer';
```

or any full path to the file.

Comment: This is the reason why I promised myself not to work late. Thank you.